# Insertion sort with numbers already in pairs

Tags: algorithm

I am currently attempting to work out the number of comparisons that is done by insertion sort when the elements are already in sorted pairs, for example

```
4,5,22,23,1,2,19,20...
```

Currently working to solve for the worst and average case number of comparisons done when a sentinel is used.

For worst case where each pair is out of order, what I've worked out is that the pattern for comparison goes `1 + 3 + 3 + 5 + 5 ... + n + n`, leading to a summation

```
\sum_{n=2}^{n/2}(2n-1)(2)
```

and I solved it to `(n^2+4/2) - 3 - (n-2)`

Does this look about right? I'm now having trouble attempting to solve for the average case. Any idea how to go about this? Thanks for any help

Comment: It seems to me that you might have more luck on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) for this question.

Comment: In you examples, the pairs are already correct w.r.t. the entire list. Is this always the case, or are they just sorted w.r.t. each other? I.e. would `[1,4, 2,5, 3,6]` also be a valid input?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare/swap a pair of adjacant number at a time, so the prolem is the same as an ordinary insertion sort on an array with a half length. Each comparation need to compare two numbers, so the average case is O((n/2)^2*2)=O(n^2/2).